# Symfony2 get choice text

Tags: symfony

If I use an integer as value on a form choice...

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('phone')
    ->add('time', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            1 => 'Morning',
            2 => 'Afternoon'
        )
    ))
```

Is there a way to access the option text?

I mean, if I store `2` on my entity, how should I render `Afternoon`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot or shouldn't do this in the way you mentioned. The proper way is to create an option resolver which will know which option is related to which id (it might be an entity or simple collection) and can return a list of available options.

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('phone')
    ->add('time', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $optionsCollection->getList()
    ));
```

And you can get the option from entity

```
$optionsCollection->getOption( $entity->getTime() );
```

On the other hand you can define the array not with ids but with proper values:

```
->add('time', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'Morning' => 'Morning',
            'Afternoon' => 'Afternoon'
        )
```

It's also some solution, much quicker to implement.

Regards, Piotr